# calling performSelectorInBackground: from background thread

Tags: multithreading, cocoa-touch, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

What is the real effect of calling `performSelectorInBackground:...` from a method that is running in the background? I want it to run asynchronously

For example:

```
- (void) _imageBufferWasUpdated{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    //do something here

    if(shouldContinue){ 
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(_loop) withObject:nil];
    }
    [pool release];
}
```

_imageBufferWasUpdated will run in the background and I want to call _loop method asynchronously (in the background also so _imageBufferWasUpdated will finish soon, probably before _loop ends).

Is this correct?

Is there a more efficient (and relatively simple) way to do this using GCD? I would appreciate it if you could give some example on how to fork this using GCD. I think I need at least 3 threads, Main thread, background thread for running _imageBufferWasUpdated and other background thread for _loop. Am I correct?

Thanks in advance
Ignacio

Comment: please somebody help me! ;) process in the background thread is extremely slow and I don't know if this is reason...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing seems fine to me. Cocoa probably uses a single background thread, so it should not lead to excessive thread creation.

If you want more control, you could use NSOperation or GCD. Both are quite simple. Eg, GCD would be like this

```
#import <dispatch/dispatch.h>

...

dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
    [self _loop];
}];
```

Comment: It can't use a single background thread;  doing so would quickly lead to deadlocks.

Comment: I think that is not exactly what I want because using dispatch_get_global_queue will make _loop run in the main thread and that loop is very busy with other stuff. Wouldn't it be something like performSelectorOnMainThread:...  rather than performSelectorOnBackgroundThread?

Comment: The default global queue does not run on the main thread. You ask for the main queue to do that. The default queue runs on background threads.

Answer (score 1):

performSelectorInBackground forks your selector to a background thread. [[documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple%5Fref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorInBackground:withObject:)]

I don't know if I'm right, but you should do everything using GCD or its high level classes (NSOperationQueue). Forking too many background threads might cause a decrease in performance if the system is saturated with too many threads and have not enough computing resources

GCD automatically manages how many threads operate concurrently based upon available system resources.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I will try GCD ;)