# How to perform processing during an animation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an app where I want to have an image animation while I am reading some info from a database and building object.  I have used UIImageView and set up and array of images, but if I start the animation and then do my DB processing, the animation does not play.

Is there another way to start the animation, or for me to do processing during the animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're doing your processing on the main thread, which is preventing your animations from running.

Animations run on the main thread, so to avoid blocking this thread processing should be scheduled on a different thread.

You can achieve this using blocks like so:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue;
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    // Your processing to be performed on this thread.
});
```

Or on earlier iOS versions, like so:

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(yourProcessing) withObject:nil];

- (void)yourProcessing {

    // Your processing to be performed on this thread.
}
```

I highly recommend a read through of the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html), followed by watching the WWDC sessions covering Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch (WWDC 2009).

Comment: Thanks for this, I am looking through it now.

Answer (score 2):

You can run your DB processing on the background thread after you begin the animation. This will allow the two to happen simultaneously.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, that is what I thought of also, however, being new to XCode, Objective C and the iPad I am in the process of looking at the way to start a thread.  Any help in that direction I would welcome. Example, snippet, etc. Thanks

Comment: @LilMoke Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422561/calling-performselectorinbackground-from-background-thread) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873200/memory-management-and-performselectorinbackground) for examples and discussions. The key is managing the autoreleasepool, but the examples show you how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you’re trying to do your database processing on the main thread, which, yes, will block your UI so it can’t animate (and so the user can’t interact with anything). Take a look at the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091).